# How to compare Excel sheets name with a list of string - Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key

I imported a multi-sheet-excel file into Python.

code :

```
import_net_data = pd.read_excel(path_file, sheet_name=None)
sheets_name_tolerated = ['POSTE', 'DEPART 1', 'DEPART 2', 'DEPART 3', 'DEPART 4', 'DEPART 5', 'DEPART 6', 'DEPART 7', 'DEPART 8', 'DEPART 9', 'DEPART 10', 'DEPART 11', 'DEPART 12', 'DEPART 13', 'DEPART 14']    
print(import_net_data.keys())
```

[image]

result:

```
dict_keys(['DEPART 1', 'DEPART 2', 'DEPART 3', 'DEPART 4', 'POSTE'])
```

I would like to check if the names of the excel sheet are matching the "sheets_name_tolerates" name. How can I proceed with the keys() that are given with pd.read_excel() function ?

I tried whithout any succes :

```
df.keys() in sheets_name_tolerated
```

Expected result :

```
True
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .keys() method on a dictionary is going to return a list

```
import_net_data = pd.read_excel(path_file, sheet_name=None)
sheets_name_tolerated = ['POSTE', 'DEPART 1', 'DEPART 2', 'DEPART 3', 'DEPART 4', 'DEPART 5', 'DEPART 6', 'DEPART 7', 'DEPART 8', 'DEPART 9', 'DEPART 10', 'DEPART 11', 'DEPART 12', 'DEPART 13', 'DEPART 14']  
retrievedList=import_net_data.keys()
matches = [i for i in sheets_name_tolerated if i in retrievedList]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! it's not exactly what I was looking for but it gave me an Idea :)
I don't manage to edit the answer (queue is full), I will add another answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks BhavinT for the help !

Here is the final code that i will use :

```
import_net_data = pd.read_excel(path_file, sheet_name=None)

sheets_name_tolerated = ['POSTE', 'DEPART 1', 'DEPART 2', 'DEPART 3', 'DEPART 4', 'DEPART 5', 'DEPART 6', 'DEPART 7', 'DEPART 8', 'DEPART 9', 'DEPART 10', 'DEPART 11', 'DEPART 12', 'DEPART 13', 'DEPART 14']
matches = all([i in sheets_name_tolerated for i in import_net_data.keys()])
```

Answer (score 0):

`.keys()` doesn't return a list need to cast. Also, you can use `in` if list of lists. Not work for same size lists.

```py
import_net_data = pd.read_excel(path_file, sheet_name=None)
sheets_name_tolerated = ['POSTE', 'DEPART 1', 'DEPART 2', 'DEPART 3', 'DEPART 4', 'DEPART 5', 'DEPART 6', 'DEPART 7', 'DEPART 8', 'DEPART 9', 'DEPART 10', 'DEPART 11', 'DEPART 12', 'DEPART 13', 'DEPART 14']  
imported_sheet_names=import_net_data.keys()

# if you have or need exact match this should be work
print(list(import_net_data.keys()) == sheets_name_tolerated)

# if your number of list items and number of sheets are same but in different order
print(set(sheets_name_tolerated) == set(imported_sheet_names))

# if your excel file has only tolerated sheet names
print(all(map(sheets_name_tolerated.__contains__, imported_sheet_names)))
```